# jQuery UI problem: why do the elements go flying around the screen?

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-ui

Yes, I know the title sounds a little suspicious. I will try to explain this the best I can...

The code below is supposed to have the blue `div` slide down beside the red `div`. (Directly to the right - using the `position()` utility of jQuery UI) The first time you hit the `Show the div` button, it works. Also, the `Hide the div` works.

Then when I click to show the `div` again, it appears to the right of where it is supposed to be! Why is this?!?

**Note:** You can find a live example of the code [here](http://files.quickmediasolutions.com/nuisance/test_case.html)

```
<html>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN"
    "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">
<head>
<title>Demo</title>
<style type='text/css'>

#red {
    background-color: red;
    width: 200px;
    height: 150px;
    position: absolute;
}

#blue {
    background-color: blue;
    width: 150px;
    height: 200px;
    position: absolute;
    display: none;
}

#tester_1 {
    top: 300px;
    left: 300px;
    position: absolute;
}

#tester_2 {
    top: 350px;
    left: 300px;
    position: absolute;
}

</style>
</head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jqueryui.js"></script>
<script type='text/javascript'>

function Show()
{
    $('#blue').position({
            of: $('#red'),
            my: 'left top',
            at: 'right top'}).slideDown();
}

function Hide()
{
    $('#blue').hide();
}

</script>
<body>
<div id='red'></div>
<div id='blue'></div>
<button id='tester_1' onclick='Show()'>Show the <kbd>div</kbd></button>
<button id='tester_2' onclick='Hide()'>Hide the <kbd>div</kbd></button>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Works well on Firefox 3.6, but not on IE8.

Comment: the only js script I found in your code is just jQuery.js. How can you say it's a jQuery UI??? please guide me I'm lost...

Comment: @Reigel: Sorry... the reason for that is I copy-and-pasted the small 4kb of jQuery UI that provides `position()` and stuck it to the end of `jquery.js`. Fixed the question now.

Comment: Try including the entire thing instead of copy pasting portions of it. You never know.

Comment: This is reproducible with the full jQuery UI, so that's not the issue. The demonstration of `position` on the jQuery site seems buggy, I'm not sure I'd use it: http://jqueryui.com/demos/position (in fact, I don't use much of jQuery UI for the same reason).

Comment: Is there a solution to this then? Cause this is quite a serious flaw in the code - it doesn't even work at all in this case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try just resetting the blue div... I did this and it appears to work on Chrome and IE now.

```
function Hide()
{
    $('#blue').css({ left: 0, top: 0 }).hide();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
function Show()
{
    $('#blue').position({
            of: $('#red'),
            my: 'left top',
            at: 'right top'})
    .slideDown();
}
```

I can't figured out what's with the parameters of your [position](http://api.jquery.com/position/).
Try to cut that to

```
   function Show()
    {
        $('#blue').slideDown();
    }
```

and it will work.

**EDIT**

based on additional comments try this

```
$(function(){
   $('#blue').position({
            of: $('#red'),
            my: 'left top',
            at: 'right top'})
})
function Show()
{
    $('#blue').slideDown();
}

function Hide()
{
    $('#blue').hide();
}
```

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to mention that the whole point of the thing is that the blue `div` is supposed to be right beside the red `div`. This sample uses jQuery UI.

Comment: it's not a bug... its just you're calling `.position()` in every clicks... that's why... and `.position()` initializes based on it's current position....

Answer (score 0):

It looks like youre trying to use jQuery UI position, but you did not reference it

http://jqueryui.com/demos/position/

Comment: Ooooooh yeah. No, the reason for that is I copy-and-pasted the small 4kb of jQuery UI that provides `position()` and stuck it to the end of `jquery.js`. I can see where the confusion is though...

Comment: yeah, i see it now. well, then thats not the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Any measurement you make (directly or via jQuery UI) when the element is hidden (using display:none) is going to yield 0. This can lead to funny results if you assume the element is visible.

In your example, you are positioning the element when it is not in the display list and then doing `slideDown()` and that's what is causing the problem.